# Regex to match keywords followed by anything but stop at the next keywords

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match `ThisAnything` and `ThatAnything` (two matches) in `ThisAnthingThatAnything`

So far I've got `/(?:This|That)(?:.*)/g` but this will match `ThisAnthingThatAnything` (one match but I want two). How do I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookahead and capture the two substrings in 2 groups:

`(This.*?(?=This|That|\b)|That.*?(?=This|That|\b))`

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/wE4fM4/3).

Result:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-11]  `ThisAnthing`
MATCH 2
1.  [11-23] `ThatAnything`
```

Comment: Oh this fails when I have more complex situation `/(((This|That).*(?=(That|This)))|((This|That).*))/` Only get two matches when I have string `ThisanfewfThatfewfweThisfwefewThisfewfeThisfewfe` Expecting five

Comment: Sorry my question is not that clear but does my previous example make sense?

Comment: Here is a regex that will return 5 matches: `(This.*?(?=This|That|\b)|That.*?(?=This|That|\b))`. Example: https://regex101.com/r/kB1bF8/2

Answer (score 1):

`split(/(?=This|That)/g)` should do the trick:

```js
s = "ThisAnthingThatAnythingThatMoreThisMore"

a = s.split(/(?=This|That)/g)
document.write(a)
```

Comment: What you mean "might work"? It does work for your test data. If your actual use case is different, please post it.

Comment: Not saying its not working... just saying I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You want a reluctant quantifier, `*?`; so your regex becomes `(This|That)(.*?)`